# jQuery encode blank space in ajax query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an API which has blank spaces in the query string.

```
stationString=KDEN%20KSEA
```

In my Ajax query i'm using it like this:

```
var station ="KDEN%20KSEA"
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=tafs&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&timeType=issue&
data: {'stationString': station},
```

My decoded URL in my console looks like this:

```
stationString:KDEN%2520KSEA
```

When I set my station variable like this:

```
var station ="KDEN KSEA"
```

My decoded URL in my console substitutes the blank space with a "+".

How can I pass a blank space in my string?

Comment: API's should accept both plus signs and `%20` as spaces, however you can just `encodeURIComponent(station)` before using it

Comment: You have `encoded` string in variable. Use `decodeURIComponent` to decode it. What is the matter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decode the string before sending it in the request so that it does not get double-encoded by jQuery's `$.ajax()` method. To do that you can use `decodeURIComponent()`. Try this:

```
var station = decodeURIComponent("KDEN%20KSEA");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=tafs&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=3&timeType=issue',
    data: { stationString: station },
    success: function(data) {
        // do something with the returned data...
    }
});
```